# IQ test matrix question - circles and squares on a vertical line

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

Another IQ question from the Mensa Romania app. What is the answer, and why?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> A. Adding the circles and squares vertically yields the last one in the column. Ex, top left has 2 circles and 1 square, middle left has no circles and 2 squares, so summing gets 2 circles and 3 squares, which is the lower left. Also, as @AngelPray mentioned in the comments - this also holds true horizontally. Probably due to mathematical relationships of addition, but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: It also works horizontally. +1